# JDK1.4.2 doesn't return IPV6 address using getHostAddress

Tags: java, ipv6, java1.4

JDK 1.5 above returns the IPV6 addresses fine. But JDK1.4.2 returns only IPV4 addresses. The OS are Windows XP and Windows 7. Anyone manages to get the IPV6 addresses on JDK 1.4.2?

```
    NetworkInterface iface = null;
    for (Enumeration ifaces = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces(); ifaces
            .hasMoreElements();) {
        iface = (NetworkInterface) ifaces.nextElement();

        InetAddress ia = null;
        for (Enumeration ips = iface.getInetAddresses(); ips
                .hasMoreElements();) {
            ia = (InetAddress) ips.nextElement();
            System.out.println(ia.getHostName());
        }

    }
```

I am suspicious that there is this native code in java.net.InetAddressImplFactory.

```
private static native boolean isIPv6Supported();
```

Since JDK1.4.2 was developed long time ago, it might not be compatible with the native library in Windows to get the IPV6 addresses. Is this correct?

Comment: 1.4.2 has **long** seen its end-of-life and is no longer supported by Oracle (unless you pay quite a handsome amount of money, in which case you should contact the Oracle support you pay for). **Please** don't support it yourself!

Comment: If you *absolutely* must use 1.4.2, then maybe [this IPv6 guide](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/net/ipv6_guide/) helps.

Comment: Additionally: I'm **pretty sure** that Windows 7 is **not** a supported platform for the publicly available JDK 1.4.2 builds.

Comment: I absolutely need to use 1.4.2, because many companies are using it and I need to support them. The document says it supports IPV6, so I am guessing there might be an way.

Comment: Tell those companies that they are using unsupported software, so you are not able to support them either.

Comment: @Mark:Yeah, try tell something like that to the managers...

Comment: @totaljj:Check this blog. http://blogs.oracle.com/alanb/entry/ipv6 This guy says that IPV6 for JDK1.4 is supported only for Linux and Solaris.Some experimental support for Windows

Comment: Then tell them there are two options: 1) Pay a big load of money to Oracle to get support or 2) upgrade to Java 6 (or 7) and maybe have some addition development work, but is cheaper.

Comment: @user384706: you can, provided you have the right arguments. And "we are wide open to security problems in the JDK, which can cost us $$$" and "we won't be able to get commercial support, if we need it, because the technology is outdated" and "developing new features and training new developers cost us x% more, because we need to train them in old, unsupported technology" might be among the useful ones.

Comment: @Joachim:Depends on who you are talking to and how badly they want to keep the customer.On the upside, you would have convinced my very easily :-)